# Firebase query where not all the documents contain requested field

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I'm using firebase on my project.
For now i'm trying to get the documents from the firebase, but facing the following problem.
Basically I have old documents which don't have `hidden` field and new ones which have it. Now I want to get each document where `hidden == fasle` and what I'm trying is the following

```
getUserDocuments(): Observable<DocumentInterface[]> {
return this.db
  .collection<DocumentInterface>(CollectionNames.DOCUMENTS, (ref) =>
    ref.where('uid', '==', this.uid).orderBy('timeCreated', 'desc').where('hidden', '==', 'false')
  )
  .valueChanges();
}
```

I've read the docs carefully and I don't get why I'm receiving empty array. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: add ur firestore

Comment: @PeterHaddad what do you mean?

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of your Firestore collection related to the above query?

Comment: Do all documents have a `timeCreated` field?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found the problem. In the `.where('hidden', '==', 'false')` I was passing the string with value `false` but in the database it was boolean so the problem was solved by removing quotes: `.where('hidden', '==', false)`.

Comment: Nice to hear that you found the solution. Please consider accepting your own answer so the community with similar issues can take a look at your solution :)